# Airflow + Nginx set up gives Airflow 404 = lots of circles

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, airflow

I'm trying to set up Airflow behind nginx, using the instructions given here.

**airflow.cfg file**

```
base_url = https://myorg.com/airflow
web_server_port = 8081
.
.
.
enable_proxy_fix = True
```

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name myorg.com;
    .
    .
    .
    location /airflow {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }
}
```

Airflow webserver and scheduler are up and running as systemd. When I try to access https://myorg.com/airflow/, it gives Airflow 404 = lots of circles.

What could be wrong? Really appreciate your help in getting this running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem and fixed it by adding a tailing `/` to the location: `location /airflow/ {` instead of `location /airflow {`. The tailing backslash tells nginx to remove the preceeding /airflow in uri paths to the corresponding python app.

My overall config looks as follows:

```
    server_name my_server.my_org.net;
    location /airflow/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9997;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

In `airflow.cfg` I additionally specified:

```
base_url = http://my_server.my_org.net/airflow
enable_proxy_fix = False  # Seems to be deprecated?
web_server_port = 9997
```

Comment: `enable_proxy_fix` is not deprecated, but you only need it when running behind an SSL proxy (the ProxyFix makes sure the generated URLs and such have the right scheme added).

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem using https.
But using the configuration in the solution led me to another problem.

Anything other than `/airflow/` location falls back to `/` location.
Returning 404 errors to assets.

Using the configuration bellow solved the issue:

```
location ^~ /airflow/ {
  proxy_pass_header Authorization;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/airflow/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
  proxy_buffering off;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
}
```

Comment: The `X-Forwarded-Server` header is rather meaningless to Airflow and ProxyFix, you can safely drop it. `X-Forwarded-Host` is ignored unless you have `proxy_fix_x_host = 1` set in your webserver section, and is also not needed because you already set the `Host` header for the proxy request.

Comment: The `^~` modifier is only needed if you have regex location rules for your server which would otherwise match. Otherwise `location /airflow/` suffices.

Comment: Yep! I have a catch all rule to PHP.