# Understanding Airflow and Nginx reverse proxy configuration on Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, airflow

I am having difficulty connecting Apache airflow to connect through a reverse proxy (Nginx) when running on Kubernetes. I have installed from the Helm [stable/airflow](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow) chart. I enabled the Ingress resource to be created. What I am trying to do is get configure Nginx ingress controller to route public IP requests to the airflow-web ClusterIP service to the airflow-web pod.

I have attempted to follow the official [documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-behind-proxy.html) and several other issues that have popped up on StackOverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105608/airflow-nginx-set-up-gives-airflow-404-lots-of-circles), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102533/kubernetes-ingress-apache-airflow), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413093/cannot-access-airflow-web-server-via-aws-load-balancer-https-because-airflow-red). All of these issues I've experienced are related to connecting airflow and Nginx. I Feel I am (as well as others) not understanding the concepts needed to tie Airflow and Nginx reverse proxy together. Is anyone able to explain the meaning of the additional configuration and why it's needed (relating to the official documentation)? I think using that as a basis I will understand how to then use that to configure it on my Kubernetes setup.